# Join line based on delimiter using awk, sed in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I'd like to join lines that end with a `|` with the next line.

Example:

```
abcd|  
ef  
123456|   
78|  
90
```

Desired output:

```
abcdef  
1234567890
```

Comment: I think it's a valid question even though poster didn't show any work.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/|\s*\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed ':a;/| *$/{N;ba};s/| *\n//g' infile
abcdef  
1234567890
```

This does the following:

```
:a          # Label to branch to
/| *$/{     # If the line ends with a pipe and optional spaces
    N       # Append next line to pattern space
    ba      # Branch to label
}
s/| *\n//g  # Remove all pipes followed by optional spaces and a newline
```

To get this working under BSD sed, the command has to be split up after labels and branching commands:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/| *$/{N;ba' -e '};s/| *\n//g' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[|]\\s*\\n' -v ORS= '1' file
abcdef
1234567890
```

With other awks one way would be:

```
$ awk 'sub(/\|[[:blank:]]*$/,"") {s = s $0; next} {print s $0; s=""}' file
abcdef
1234567890
```

If your last input line can end with `|` you'd need to tell us how to handle that and add sample input/output including that case to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed ':loop; /| *$/{N;s/\n//g}; t loop' yourfile | sed 's/ *| *//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue! The following script removes pipe characters and newlines when they occur.

```
$ awk '{c=sub(/\|/,"")?"":"\n"; $1=$1; printf "%s%s",$0,c}' file
abcdef
1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

I started with this

```
awk -F '|' 'NF>1 {printf "%s", $1} NF==1' file
```

But then I thought that made too many assumptions about how many fields you might have. So I ended up with

```
awk -F '|' '{if (NF>1 && $NF ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/) {NF--; printf "%s", $0} else print}' file
```

which is much sturdier but less terse.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the input text is stored in a file name `infile`

You can use this GNU sed command:
`sed  ':begin;$!N;s/\n//;s/\s//g;s/|//g' infile`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\|/,"")}{printf "%s",$1}/f/{print "\r"}END {print ""}' file
abcdef
1234567890
```